# event bus in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mainly using Vue, and just recently picked up React. Loving it so far, and its quite similar in a lot of ways to Vue, which makes learning it way easier.

Now, let's consider two siblings component. I want to trigger something in component number one, when something happens in component number two. In Vue you can just bind `window.bus = new Vue`, and then emit in one of the components `bus.$emit('event')` and bind in the `mounted()` of the second component `bus.$on('event', this.doSth)`.

How can you achieve that in React?

Comment: The React way would be to have the parent of the components pass a callback to one of the components, which the component calls. The parent then does something with the data and rerenders, passing the data to the other component. Of course you could also just use any pubsub library and hook up the components directly. It's really up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ill take a look at the pubsub libraries too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent component can manage the `state` and methods consumed by child components when passed down through `props`.

The following example increments a count. `SibOne` displays the count and a button in `SibTwo` increments the count.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        };
    }
    incrementCount = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <SibOne count={this.state.count}/>
                <SibTwo incrementCount={this.incrementCount}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const SibOne = props => <div>Count: {props.count}</div>;

const SibTwo = props => (
    <button onClick={props.incrementCount}>
        Increment Count
    </button>
);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/zqp9wj2n63

More on **Components and Props**: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Though this is not an event bus.

Answer (score 13):

Event Bus is only a Global Function Register, can you use it

```
class _EventBus {

    constructor() {
        this.bus = {};
    }

    $off(id) {
       delete this.bus[id];
    }

    $on(id, callback) {
        this.bus[id] = callback;
    }

    $emit(id, ...params) {
        if(this.bus[id])
            this.bus[id](...params);
    }
}

export const EventBus = new _EventBus();
```

The `export const` prevent multiple instances, making the class static

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23986980)

Answer (score 3):

In the case of two sibling components, you would hold the state in the parent component and pass that state as a prop to both siblings:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = {
   specialProp: "bar"
  }

  changeProp = () => {
   // this.setState.. 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FirstSibling specialProp={this.state.specialProp} />
        <SecondSibling changeProp={this.changeProp} specialProp={this.state.specialProp} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that are still searching, look at this article: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-communicate-between-independent-components-in-reactjs

The solution uses:

`document.addEventListener` for `$on`;

`document.dispatchEvent` for `$emit`;

`document.removeEventListener` for `$off`;

In my use case I had a component that contained a Refresh button that would trigger a data refresh in other components.

I did everything as it was presented in the article. In case you're using React with Functional Components, you might want to use the following useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // The component might unmount when the request is in progress.
    // Because of this an error will appear when we'll try to 'setData'.
    let isMounted = true

    const getData = () => {
      reqData(db, path)
        .then(result => {
          if (isMounted) {
            setData(result) // This is a useState
          }
        })
    }

    eventBus.on('refreshData', (data) => {
      getData()
    })

    getData()

    return () => {
      isMounted = false
      eventBus.remove('refreshData')
    }

    // Do not change the end of this useEffect. Keep it as it is. It simulates componentDidMount.
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Write-Once, use everywhere Event Bus (PubSub) system

I have used Vue for a long time and I enjoyed using the Event Bus too, was a pain that it wasn't readily available on react. Although, after a lot of research, I came up with an approach that should be easy to implement.

You can leverage Event Listeners and the `CustomEvent` API to implement the Event Bus architecture.

```
// event-bus.js file

const EventBus = {

  $on (eventType, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, (ev) => callback(ev.detail))
  },

  $dispatch (eventType, data) {
    const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, { detail: data })
    document.dispatchEvent(event)
  },

  $remove (eventType, callback) {
    document.removeEventListener(eventType, callback)
  }
}

export default EventBus
```

You can now go ahead to import the `EventBus` object to any file of choice, here is what the usage looks like for me.

**For the publisher:**

```
// publisher.js file
EventBus.$dispatch(message.name, message.value)
```

**And on the subscriber's end:**

```
// subscriber.js file
EventBus.$on('user.connect', (data) => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

rxjs is one more option that you can explore. check if that can help you as they are providing observable and event based programs. It is also doing similar thing like what Eventbus is doing in vuejs.